# How do change the format to percent in a list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices, where i want to change the values in the matrices to percent.

The matrices in the list look like this

```
       [,1]     [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       
Year     ""    "2010"      "2011"      "2012"      "2013"      "2014"      "2015"      "2016"      "2017"     
Women "Women"  "0.4521919" "0.4360186" "0.4344594" "0.4314785" "0.4363432" "0.4402187" "0.4437688" "0.4414514"
Men    "Men"   "0.5478081" "0.5639814" "0.5655406" "0.5685215" "0.5636568" "0.5597813" "0.5562312" "0.5585486"
```

Which I want to convert into

```
       [,1]     [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       
Year     ""    "2010"      "2011"      "2012"      "2013"      "2014"      "2015"      "2016"      "2017"     
Women "Women"  "45.21919%" "43.60186%" "43.44594%" "43.14785%" "43.63432%" "44.02187%" "44.37688%" "44.14514%"
Men    "Men"   "54.78081%" "56.39814%" "56.55406%" "56.85215%" "56.36568%" "55.97813%" "55.62312%" "55.85486%"
```

I've tried to do this using `lapply`

```
x <- lapply(df, function(x) percent(as.numeric(x[2:nrow(x),(3:ncol(x))])))
```

But this returns one vector of characters rather than two rows which then could be returned to the desired format with `cbind`. The values being characters isn't really an issue, but numeric values would be prefered.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make a nice solution to the problem above. Grateful for all tips!

/J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix can only hold one data type. Transform each matrix to a data.frame using  `as.data.frame()` in order to be able to have different data types in a same data structure. You could also remove the first column of each matrix, which should work as well since it seems it is the only `character` value in your data structure.

Answer (score 3):

While I would use `data.frame` instead of a matrix, but this may depend on what your end goal is. You could subset the matrix and append a % sign.

```
xy <- matrix(runif(9), nrow = 3)
xy[, 1] <- c("", "men", "women")
xy[1, ] <- c("", "2010", "2011")
xy[-1, -1] <- paste(as.numeric(xy[-1, -1]) * 100, "%")

xy
     [,1]    [,2]                 [,3]                
[1,] ""      "2010"               "2011"              
[2,] "men"   "85.1143697509542 %" "11.8173067457974 %"
[3,] "women" "89.0305595472455 %" "64.4668221008033 %"
```

Comment: @RHertel nice catch, fixed.